# Package electron js app for raspberry pi 4b/cm4/zero 2 w

Tags: raspberry-pi, electron

I made a UI app in electron JS for one of my projects on PC and I want to package it for raspberry pi.

1. Is it a problem that I made the app using windows and will everything work on linux that worked on windows?
2. Is there a difference in the packaging when you build for raspberry pi 4/cm4 vs when you build for zero 2 w?
3. How exactly can I package it? (electron builder / electron packager / forge/ or something else entirely) ?

I couldn't figure out all this by myself so any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

So I had to learn a lot of this about a year ago, I'm the founder of an Electron app for Power BI called [Displagent](https://www.displagent.io), and I had to run Displagent on Raspberry Pis.

Here is what I've done:

- My code is stored on a private GitHub repository. I develop and test locally on a Windows machine.
- I use Electron Builder.
- Each OS has OS-specific node packages that it needs *at build time*, so you need Electron Builder to build the executable artifacts on each OS.
- To do this, I setup some advanced CI/CD with [CircleCI](https://circleci.com/). When I push to my `main` branch or merge a PR into `main`, I have a CircleCI script that runs and autobuilds my Electron app on Windows, Mac, and Linux on their cloud servers.
- Then I take the build artifacts and store them somewhere for download by users. I use Azure BLOB storage, but you can use AWS, Google Cloud platform, whatever.

That seems to get the job done.

Here are some snippets from my CircleCI YAML script:

```yaml
# This config is equivalent to both the '.circleci/extended/orb-free.yml' and the base '.circleci/config.yml'
version: 2.1

# Orbs are reusable packages of CircleCI configuration that you may share across projects, enabling you to create encapsulated, parameterized commands, jobs, and executors that can be used across multiple projects.
# See: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/orb-intro/
orbs:
  node: circleci/node@5.1.0
  win: circleci/windows@5.0

jobs:
    build-windows-prod:
      executor: win/server-2022
      working_directory: ~/repo
      steps:
         #Do stuff...

    build-linux-prod:
      machine:
        image: ubuntu-2004:current 
      working_directory: ~/repo
      steps:
         #Do stuff...
```

Hope that helps.